# anchor init PDA => result = error : Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large

Tags: anchor, pda

i'm stucked at something i've done many many times, and i don't get the problem.
I want to init a PDA, i use the following code :

`#[account( init, payer = owner, seeds = [METADATA_ACCOUNT_PREFIX.as_bytes(), mint.key().as_ref()], token::mint = mint, token::authority = owner, bump, )] pub real_metadata_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,`

if i comment it, everything works as expected, but as soon as i uncomment it i get the following error:

Program failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933556 > 1280)

Like if the program fails to init the account in the inner instruction, but i don't get why there would be that much data.

I used many times init with similar seeds, and never had any problem.
for information, i tried with different mint addresses.

metadata_account_prefix is just a string of letters.

any idea ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, when i downgrade the solana version then i won't able to build my program through `anchor build` cmd.
Do i need to downgrade my anchor version as well?

Answer (score 3):

Was stuck on this forever too.

Found this issue directly on Github and followed: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2520

I advise to eliminate the current version of solana on your pc since 1.16.0 seems to creating problems.

Find the origin of the Solana Folder by using

```
which Solana
```

Eliminate the folder by navigating upstream till probably the .local folder and doing

```
rm -R solana
```

Then install the version 1.14.18

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.14.18/install)"
```

Let me know if that solves it!

Comment: You could actually have different versions of solana on your system using `solana-install`.

switch to a different solana version using `solana-install init 1.14.18`

No need to find and remove the solana folder.